# Function environment Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am doing a Shiny app, and the last piece I want is the user be able to enter numeric values for some parameters.
Before that, those parameters were raw, and directly inside one function. Everything worked fine.

So the code is all about running the "big_function". This "big_function" uses many other functions that are loaded with `source` at the beginning of the code. All the loaded functions appear in the global environment afterward.

The "intermediaire_function" is the one I need to modify to allow new parameters. In my "big_function", the "intermediaire_function" appears many time, in differents functions.
To avoid too many change in the code, and also to avoid too many parameters in my "big_function" (it has more than 3 actually), I thought about just create a "intermediaire_function_wParam", and in the code, define a new "intermediaire_function" as below, with the desired parameters.

But, then, when I run the app, I get an error, because my "big_function" cannot find the "intermediaire_function" that it needs. If I "validate" the new "intermediaire_function" by hand, and run again the app, it works.

So, it looks like when I define my new "intermediaire_function" function, shiny does not put it in a global environement, like it does with the `source`.

I tried to define it before the `ui`, at different places, but nothing works, and I don't understand why.

Once this works, I want to pass as parameters the user's input. That's why it's in comment so far.

```
list_package <- c("shiny", "shinythemes", "tidyverse", "readxl", "openxlsx")

filenames <- list.files("R functions/", pattern="*.R", full.names=TRUE)
sapply(filenames, source)


ui <- fluidRow(
     column(4,
            numericInput("a_ST_TM", value = 0.25, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.05)
     ),
     column(4, offset = 1,
            numericInput("b_ST_TM", value = 0.15, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.05)
     ),
     column(3, 
            actionButton("run_global", "Run")
            )
   )


# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  intermediaire_function <- function(n, Tail){
    intermediaire_function_wParam(n, Tail, a_ST = 0.5, b_ST =  0.1)
    # a_ST = input$a_ST_TM, b_ST = input$b_ST_TM)
  }

  observeEvent(input$run_global, {
    big_function(input$path_res, input$path_prem, input$select_year)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If nothing else works, you could maybe pass the intermediary function as a parameter to the big_function: `big_function(input$path_res, input$path_prem, input$select_year, intermediaire_function)`, and make sure big_function is able to use this parameter.

Comment: @Bas Thank you! I might pass the parameters of my intermediaire function to the big_function, and do the trick at the beginning of the big_function. But still, I really don't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: Well, I did try what I wrote in the previous comment, and I got the same error...

Comment: @Bas I used your answer, and it worked! At least I was to do what I wanted. I still don't understand why the first one didn't work, but nevermind